# Broadcast in a hypercube with MPI

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm trying to broadcast a vector full of **1** from process **0** in a *hypercube*

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int myRank, nProc;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myRank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nProc);
  MPI_Request request;
  MPI_Status status; 

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  double start = MPI_Wtime();

  std::vector<int> vector(100, 0);
  if (myRank == 0) {vector = std::vector<int>(100, 1);}

  //Broadcast in a hypercube
  int dimension = log2(nProc);

  for (int step = 0 ; step < dimension ; step++) {
    std::bitset<6> tmpRank(myRank);
    if (tmpRank >> step == 0) { //source
      int neighbor = static_cast<int>(tmpRank.flip(step).to_ulong()); //The neighbor of a source at the step i is the i_th bit flipped, re-converted to int in order to send
      MPI_Send(vector.data(), vector.size(), MPI_INT, neighbor, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else { //destination ( if(rank >> step == 1) )
      //MPI_Status status;
      MPI_Irecv(vector.data(), vector.size(), MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
    }
  }
  //

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  double end = MPI_Wtime();

  std::cout << "I am process " << myRank << " last element of my vector after broadcast is " << vector.back() << std::endl;

  if (myRank==0) std::cout << " operation time : " << end-start << "[s]" << std::endl;

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I have in output :

> ```
>  I am process 0 last element of my vector after broadcast is 1
>  operation time : 3.40939e-05[s]
>  I am process 1 last element of my vector after broadcast is 1
>  I am process 2 last element of my vector after broadcast is 1
>  I am process 3 last element of my vector after broadcast is 0
> ```

Why the last process didn't receive the vector ? The error must come from the **send** and **receive** but I don't know which function I should use (Isend, Irecv, Send, Recv).
Thanks

Comment: Since you use `MPI_Irecv()` you must `MPI_Wait()` before accessing the receive buffer. Or you can simply `MPI_Recv()`. Note `MPI_Bcast()` should be used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **must explicitly complete** all nonblocking communications (in your case `MPI_Irecv`) before accessing any participating data. That means you can neither forward the data nor print it out because completion. Use `MPI_Wait`, `MPI_Test` or any of it's `any`/`some`/`all` variants as appropriate.

If you don't need a nonblocking communication, as your example indicates, use a blocking one (i.e. `MPI_Recv`) instead.

Practically, use collectives instead of point to point when possible, in your case `MPI_Bcast`. Implementing your own broadcast isn't a good idea unless you want to learn or really know what you are doing.